# when date value is null then type

Tags: sql, date

i need to replace if the date value is dull i need to type 'TBD'

Trying these but i have error as below;

```
select name,
    CASE 
    WHEN VisitDate IS NULL THEN 'TBD'
    ELSE visitdate END
from table
```

the error is

```
Error converting data type varchar to bigint.
   Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
```

Comment: If VisitDate is of date type, then I would probably keep null as null. You cannot mix date type with string or int type. If you really want to put something in there in a select query, then you could cast all dates as string in your query. Or, keep as date and use something like 9999-12-31 as your "tbd" date.

Answer (score 0):

Date values **are not strings**. You can't put the string value `TBD` in a column that's expected to hold dates. To fix this, you have two options:

1. (preferred) Return `NULL` instead of `TBD`, and let the client code or reporting tool handle the substitution.
2. Cast the date value as a varchar before doing the NULL check.

While I'm here, you could also simplify that `CASE` expression to `COALESCE()` or `ISNULL()` call:

```
COALESCE(cast(VisitDate As varchar(10)), 'TBD') VisitDate
```

But again: this is the *less optimal* solution.

---

Finally, I'm concerned by the error message. It makes it sound like the `VisitDate` column is actually stored using `BigInt` values, which would be a poor way to handle dates.